# Marking scheme did something I don't understand, please help.

Tags: cubics

In the marking scheme they somehow manipulated a cubic to retrieve one of the factors needed to answer the question:
[image]

My question is: How can it be known to do this baring in mind there is three roots and the others had many decimals? Its like they pulled it from nowhere.

Comment: Software such as *Mathematica* factors your cubic instantly.

Comment: You can guess that $2$ is a root, check it, and then apply the [factorization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials).

Comment: Apparently you were supposed to trial and error a few values ($0$, $1$, $2$... and perhaps their negatives) which would lead you to detect that $2$ is a root.

Comment: As so often in "answers at the back of the book", they've got it wrong. The factorisation is $(k-2)(k^2+5k-26)$.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just didn't realise the question wanted trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(k)=k^{3}+3k^{2}-36k+52$. Since $p(2)=0$, the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

gives that $k-2$ is a factor of $p(k)$.

You then divide the polynomial $p(k)$ by $k-2$ to obtain the quotient $k^{2}+5k-26$. Thus, $p(k)=(k-2)(k^{2}+5k-26)$.  This is the correct factorization.

Comment: Thanks. I do know about the factor theorem but it just seems strange that they would've of wanted the reader to do all that when the question was about matrices originally lol.

Comment: Well, if you're finding eigenvalues, you need to know how to do this.

Comment: @DevinJC You haven‘t shown us the matrix for which this is the characteristic polynomial. It might be in some way obvious that one of its eigenvalues is $2$.

Comment: @amd Haven't learnt about them at all so I didn't think of posting the original matrix sorry.